# Traefik & LetsEncrypt - DNS prob lem NXDOMAIN looking up A for example.com

Tags: ssl, docker-swarm, lets-encrypt, traefik

Hopefully, this post is going to help others with the same issue I had.

Let's say you are using Docker Swarm and you use Traefik as a reverse proxy. Everything is working fine but now you need to set up SSL.

When I was using acme.httpChallenge as specified in the [doc](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/), I was always getting `DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for example.com`

I had set `defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]` to my `toml` file and www.example.com alongside example.com as type A DNS in Digital Ocean. (These are the two solutions I could find)

And still, I had a NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID when browsing to https://example.com

Answer (score 0):

First, this post was possible thanks to the Traefik team that pointed out that it was a problem with my DNS provider.

My DNS where handled by Digital Ocean (where I was registering my A type DNS for example.com and www.example.com) BUT ALSO handled by GoDaddy, and let's encrypt was only requesting the GoDaddy side. **So it did not work until I removed GoDaddy from the DNS handlers.**

Hopefully, you find this post if you got the same issue. That's a frustrating one because it is very silly, but when you are not a DevOps, it is far from obvious...

Good luck!

Comment: You identified the problem but I'm not seeing the solution.  How did you get letsecript to also hit the Digital Ocean side?

Comment: @ChaseWestlye it doesn't "also hit the Digital Ocean side", as stated above, you have to "remove GoDaddy from the DNS handlers" which  means to go to https://account.godaddy.com/products/ and click "DNS" and then change the nameserver to digital ocean's ones. After that, GoDaddy is no longer able to control the DNS at all.